# How to make two webpages update eachother?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-applications, real-time

I am currently making an online coding compiler similar to Google Docs. So, it will basically allow multiple users to write code and the other users can see that code updated in real time. However, I do not know how to make the webpages (that will have the same url) update each other in real time.  Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As @Doorknob said, you will want to look at websockets. [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) is a great, easy to use implementation. Here is a railscast that may help you get started:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye

And even better yet, you can look at using a framework like [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) that provides realtime updating across clients by default.